# AppleScript (Javascript): Remove class, if

Tags: javascript, class, applescript

How can I remove each class on Safari, only for specific text ?

I know this script bellow would remove every class named  :

> sortable itemDescription

```
tell application "Safari Technology Preview" to ¬
    do JavaScript ¬
        "document.querySelectorAll(\"[class=\\\"sortable itemDescription\\\"]\").forEach(el => el.remove());" in current tab of window 1
```

But can I add an if statement to only remove the class if the text is, in this exemple :

> "(unwanted") :

```
<td class="sortable itemDescription">

                                    (unwanted)

                            </td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lambda within the `.forEach` can be expanded to include an additional condition on performing the remove, to check the text. The text content of an element can be obtained with `.textContent`. Since there is plenty of whitespace around the actual text, `.trim()` can be used to extract the actual text for comparison.

```
document.querySelectorAll("[class=\"sortable itemDescription\"]")
    .forEach(el => {
        if (el.textContent.trim() === "(unwanted)") {
          el.remove();
        }
    });
```

---

The AppleScript is superfluous to the question. Looking at just the JavaScript, the current code in the question that is being asked about is as follows:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[class=\"sortable itemDescription\"]").forEach(el => el.remove());
```

Some escaping of quotes is needed to put the solution in this answer back into AppleScript:

```
tell application "Safari Technology Preview" to ¬
    do JavaScript ¬
        "document.querySelectorAll(\"[class=\\\"sortable itemDescription\\\"]\").forEach(el => { if (el.textContent.trim() === \"(unwanted)\") { el.remove(); } });" in current tab of window 1
```